# svn: export a folder from a particular commit from a remote git repository

Tags: git, svn

I have a git repository for example:

```
github.com/user/someproject
```

It has 10 commits in this repo

I want to get a specific folder `add_function` from 5th commit

I know using svn we can export a folder from a git repo:

```
$ svn ls https://github.com/user/someproject
/branches
/trunk
```

then go to trunk

```
$ svn ls https://github.com/user/someproject/trunk
..
add_function
...
```

Now to export the `add_function` folder we can do it by

```
$ svn export https://github.com/user/someproject/trunk/add_function
```

But here i am only able to export the `add_function` folder from the latest commit where HEAD points to i.e 10th commit. But now how to get the `add_function` folder from the 5th commit

I know the url of the 5th commit from the github website:

```
https://github.com/user/someproject/tree/40030basdsebb44b1bd42e465ca38eb3146c3
```

Now i tried

```
$ svn export https://github.com/user/someproject/40030basdsebb44b1bd42e465ca38eb3146c3/add_function
svn: E170000: https://github.com/user/someproject/40030basdsebb44b1bd42e465ca38eb3146c3/add_function doesn't exist
```

Comment: Use `--revision` (or `-r`) command parameter.

Comment: what is the argument for revision. is it commit hash

Comment: thank you @Dialecticus. I did `svn log  https://github.com/user/someproject`. Then it shows r1, r2, r3 etc and the commit message. then i did `svn ls -r5 https://github.com/user/someproject/trunk` and then `svn export -r5 https://github.com/user/someproject/trunk/add_function`